# Convert Excel sheet having shivaji fonts to csv having google unicode utf-8 encoding

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, unicode, utf-8

I have an Excel file which uses Shivaji fonts and I want to convert it to csv file using google's unicode utf-8 encoding.

I have tried all the methods but I didn't get any result because when saving file as csv it shows ? symbols I need are something like this: `Ã Â¤ÂÃ Â¤â€¢Ã Â¤Å¸Ã Â¤Â¾`.

I need to import this file to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You say "Shivaji font" -- I assume that is for Devanagari characters?

I think what you have has been misconverted twice.

I simulated it by misconverting `इंग्लिश` to `à¤‡à¤‚à¤—à¥%C2%8Dà¤²à¤¿à¤¶` and then misconverting that to `Ã Â¤â€¡Ã Â¤â€šÃ Â¤â€”Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â²Ã Â¤Â¿Ã Â¤Â¶`, which looks a lot like what you have.

When you copied the file around it got converted from utf8 to latin1 twice.  Figure out the steps you took in more detail.  If you can get a dump at any stage, do so.  The hex Devanagari characters looks like `E0A4yy` where `yy` is between `80` and `B1`.